# How to restrict Directory access using an extended java.lang.SecurityManager

Tags: java, security

I have a stand alone program named **TestProgram.java** .
I want to restrict the access of the program to only a specific directory named **"C:\Playground"**.
If the  program tries to access any other folder other than this, it needs to throw a **SecurityException** 
After going through some of the articles on **java.lang.SecurityManager**,
I am thinking of extending the SecurityManager and overriding the *checkRead(String File)* by checking if the file path provided is a child of **"C:\Playground"**.

*I do not prefer to create the policy file and mention the permissions there. Managing an extra file is an overhead for me. But if that's the better option, then how do i do it?*

1. Do I need to override *checkRead(FileDecriptor)* and  *checkRead(String file, Object context)* also? For the first method how do i find out if the filedescriptor is a child?
2. Is there a better alternative?
3. Suggest some decent books on managing security in Java.